# Single use of COUNT in CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column MessageId and have to take the count of distinct MessageId and if the result is 1, then have to display count as 0 else the count value itself. If the data set is more, using distinct twice is going to be a bit more time consuming.

```
...
CASE 
   WHEN count(DISTINCT MessageId) = 1 
      THEN 0
   ELSE count(DISTINCT MessageId)
END as Count
...
```

Is there anyway to use COUNT(DISTINCT) only once using a single query itself? And also don't want to use multiple queries like assigning it to a variable and then using it.

Comment: Why do you want to use COUNT(DISTINCT MessageId) only once? If your CASE expression appears in the SELECT clause in the runtime, the engine evaluates the expression only once and reuses the result anyway, so you don't get any performance benefit from rephrasing it defferently.

Comment: @Thinkeye Is it so? Is there any supporting document which states that?

Comment: No, but the reuse of subexpressions is one of the oldest optimization techniques when you implement expression evaluation. Every (R)DBMS developer tries to optimize away the DB engine calls, because they are expensive in terms of performance. I can't imagine a situation where SQLite developers would miss it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT MessageId), 1), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need below

```
case when sum( case when MessageId= 1 then 1 else 0 end) =1
then 0  else
count(DISTINCT MessageId) end as cnt
```